# Inserir 0 quando tiver 10 números

Tags: regex, sublime-text

Eu tenho a seguinte sequência:

```
3531399402
```

Possui 10 números, com essa regex eu consigo listar estas ocorrências:

```
^\d{10}$
```

Estou usando um editor de texto e eu preciso dar um replace nessas ocorrências e inserir um 0 antes ficando assim:

```
03531399402
```

Como eu posso fazer ?

Comment: Qual editor? Notepad++? Eclipse?

Comment: `Sublime Text` é o editor.

Comment: Uma alternativa é por tudo num agrupamento e usar a retrospectiva, algo mais ou menos como `s/^(\d{10})$/0\1/`

Comment: Não entendi bem rsrs, e eu colei aqui e não funfou.

Comment: Bota na pesquisa `^(\d{10})$` (igual ao seu exemplo, mas com um parênteses ao redor dos caracteres); no campo de substituição por `0\1`; esse `\1` é um componente de retrospecção, vai ser substituído pelo conteúdo do primeiro grupo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você deve inserir um capture group. 
 
Assim você pode identificar o replace através do grupo e usá-lo novamente com o que deseja inserir. 
Sugiro que tente mudar sua regex para:

```
^(\d{10})$
```

E use para o replace:

```
0$1
```

Isso indica que o replace deve ser feito inserindo 0 e o capture group 1 que nesse caso são os 10 dígitos que você mencionou na pergunta.

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.

Comment: É obrigatório o uso do () ?

Comment: @Douglas é obrigatório, pois a substituição depende do grupo de captura, que é indicado por "()", sem isso o "$1" não indicaria nada, pois não haveria um grupo 1.